# Yammer API - Creating a post on Yammer

Tags: yammer

I'm trying to use the Yammer API to create a post on Yammer,
I have the following code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>YammerNotification - Version 1</title>
    <script src="https://assets.yammer.com/platform/yam.js"></script>
    <script>
        yam.config({ appId: "APP-ID" });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick='post()'>Post on Yammer!</button>
    <script>
        function post() {
            yam.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    yam.request(
                      {
                          url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json"
                      , method: "POST"
                      , data: { "body": "This Post was Made Using the Yammer API.  Welcome to the Yammer API World." }
                      , success: function (msg) { alert("{Post was Successful!}: " + msg); }
                      , error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); }
                      }
                    )
                } else {
                    yam.login(function (response) {
                        if (!response.authResponse) {
                            yam.request(
                              {
                                  url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json"
                              , method: "POST"
                              , data: { "body": "This Post was Made Using the Yammer API.  Welcome to the Yammer API World." }
                              , success: function (msg) { alert("{Post was Successful!}: " + msg); }
                              , error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); }
                              }
                            );
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Although what would my APP ID be? And how do I tell it what group I want to put a post to?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

## yammer

Answer (score 4):

```
...what would my APP ID be?
```

You'd need to register an app as documented here - https://developer.yammer.com/introduction/#gs-registerapp and your APP ID is the client ID's value

```
And how do I tell it what group I want to put a post to?
```

Specify the groupID in your json data input:

```
 data: {
 "body": "This Post was Made Using the Yammer API.  Welcome to the Yammer API World."
 ,"group_id" : groupID
 }
```

See full sample code here - http://blogs.technet.com/b/israelo/archive/2014/10/21/yammer-js-sdk-for-dummies.aspx